# Crystal Formula field - Splitting a string array of numbers, summing them, and returning the total returns a boolean instead of a number

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

This is in Crystal reports 2008, all service packs installed. 
I'm trying to use a formula field to take a string field of space delimited numbers, sum them and return the total.

Code below. Always displays true on the report in preview and printed. Not entirely sure if I'm formatting the field box on the report wrong or if the output is wrong but I'm sure it's something silly.

Any pointer in the right direction would be super appreciated!

```
//Sample Field Values
//4.00    12.00   13.5   1  1  1  1
//3.00    12.50   13.5   1  1.5  1.5  1.5
```

```
Numbervar LabourHrsINT;
Local Numbervar i;
Stringvar Array output:= Split({CR_VEH_HIST_.LABHRS}," ");

LabourHrsINT := 0;
for i := 1 to ubound(output) do (

    LabourHrsINT := LabourHrsINT + (if NumericText(output[i]) then
        Val(output[i]))

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is not evaluating to the value of the sum. The last thing in your formula should be the final value of `LabourHrsINT`.

```
Numbervar LabourHrsINT:=0;
Local Numbervar i;
Stringvar Array output:= Split({CR_VEH_HIST_.LABHRS}," ");

for i := 1 to ubound(output) do (

  if NumericText(output[i]) then
     LabourHrsINT := LabourHrsINT + Val(output[i])
);

LabourHrsINT
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing the numeric check first and then doing the addition.

```
(if NumericText(output[i]) then
    LabourHrsINT := LabourHrsINT + Val(output[i]))
```